# How to resolve Depreciation warning when using moment with Javascript Date to format a string

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am getting this warning from moment.js:

```
deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.
Arguments: [object Object]
```

This is the typescript that is running:

```
moment(value).format('MMM Do, YYYY');
```

It produces: Sep 3rd, 2016

The 'value' that is being passed is a Javascript Date type, not a string.  So I do not understand why the warning is being issued.

I have read the link, but it doesn't seem to apply.  Is there something another way I should be formatting a js date type?

Comment: How certain are you that `value` is really a Date instance and not a string?

Comment: Not 100%. I will add code to check and make sure.

Comment: As far as I can tell that's about parsing string dates when there's no explicit format string. It'll accept ISO dates but nothing else (or something like that).

Comment: Is there another way I am supposed to format a Date object?

Comment: I don't think you would be getting that deprecation warning if you were really passing in a Date instance.

Comment: Ok, I checked, and it's not actually a date object, it's a string like this: 9/3/2016.  If you want to post answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deprecation is from a Moment bug back in 2014. Because the implementations of Date constructors in various JavaScript environments are not consistent, the Moment team decided to deprecate the practice of falling back to the platform's date parser for parsing strings. If you have a date string and you know the format, you can pass an explicit format string and you won't get that exception.

Thus, I think it's safe to conclude that you're *not* passing a Date instance to the `moment()` constructor, but a date string that's triggering the warning.